# Limit which ports a user can bind

Tags: linux, bind, port, users

I'm working on a setup for a Linux based system in which user applications are executed in [Linux Containers](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/) to provide confinement and limited capabilities. Each application is launched under in a container with a specific user ID.

Now, given that some of these applications are going to have server roles, I would like to be able to control which ports a specific user can bind (both TCP and UDP). One solution is manually polling `/proc/net/(tcp|udp)6`? but this is very inefficient for obvious reasons. So, I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: By "Linux Containers" do you mean [LXC](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Yep, but that is somewhat besides the point, as LXC simply relies on kernel modules. I'm investigating GRSecurity as a possiblity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AppArmor](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/AppArmor_Core_Policy_Reference#Network_rules) and [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org/page/ObjectClassesPerms#common_socket) can be used to restrict network access by processes.

Comment: AppArmor turned out to be the good solution. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is also iptables user match.

Comment: an example would be nice :)

Comment: The iptables user match only works for OUTPUT chain so I don't think it's a good solution. Your app will be able to open the port and receive data but NOT sending. It really depends on the protocol you use through this port (http, ...). If the protocol you use needs negociation/exchange before being able to be used, you can use this...